# What is wrong with the proof of $\ell_1$ is nonreflexive?

Tags: functional-analysis, proof-verification, banach-spaces

Recall that
$$\ell_1 = \{(x_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}: \sum_{n=1}^\infty |x_n|<\infty\}$$
and
$$\ell_2 = \{(x_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}: \sum_{n=1}^\infty |x_n|^2<\infty\}.$$

> Known facts:
>
> $(1)$ $\ell_1$ and $\ell_2$ are Banach spaces. In particular, $\ell_1$ is closed.
>
> $(2)$  $\ell_2$ is reflexive.
>
> $(3)$ $\ell_1\subseteq \ell_2$.
>
> $(4)$ Closed subspace of a reflexive space is again reflexive.
>
> Therefore, $\ell_1$ is reflexive.

But it is a well-known fact that $\ell_1$ is never reflexive.
What is wrong with the above arguments?

Comment: Why do you think that $\ell_1$ is a closed subspace of $\ell_2?$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\ell_1$ is not closed as a subspace of $\ell_2$: when you say $\ell_1$ is closed, you mean that it is closed with respect to the $\lVert \cdot \rVert_1$ norm, while when we consider it as a subspace of $\ell_2$ we are talking about the $\lVert \cdot \rVert_2$ norm.

To see that $\ell_1$ is not closed in $\ell_2$, just take an element $x$ of $\ell_2$ which is not in $\ell_1$, as for example is $(\frac{1}{n})_n$, and build a sequence of elements in $\ell_1$ which converge to $x$ in $\lVert \cdot \rVert_2$ norm. It should be easy for you do find many such examples.